# Sending out email through workflow using multiple checkboxes via a checkbox for each item that looks for the value "yes"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list of a dozen users on a form where a client decides via checkbox on who to send the (same) email to. At the moment I have the workflow check each item per line if the value is yes to send an email to each check boxed entry via the checkbox being ticked.
Instead of a workflow statement for each and every email created for each ( they are the same email ) isn't there a cleaner simpler way to check if each user's checkbox was selected to send an email and then create one "send an email"?
SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Geeze it's been quiet here lately.
Usually some guru is quick to bestow their expertise.

Via a workflow , I run a check  individually to see if each of the dozen email are checked "yes" if so then they are added to a local variable called "email-group". Each time  So each time one is added it is added to the previous "email_group"  ( i.e. John.Smeagle@uhm.com;[email_group] and finally use the local variable at the bottom of the all if-elses and make the variable the TO: address, selecting variable as opposed to a current item..etc.
HTH Cheers!